# how to compare multiple files, for eg: compare first and second , then compare second and third inside a loop using python?

Tags: python, list

I want to store each diff from the comparison inside the list. list will be different with each comparison.

eg: compare f1 and f2 , in list 1
    compare f2 and f3, in list 2

How to do that in python?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use zip taking the list and chopping off the last element and the same list again and chopping off the first element:

```
# ~ Create a list ~ #
x=list(range(1,5))

# ~ Find difference of elements ~ #
diff_elems = [a-b for a,b in zip(x[:-1],x[1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the files, you could just load them into lists and then take a set of that.

```py
with open(file1) as f1:
    file1_lines = f1.readlines()

with open(file2) as f2:
    file2_lines = f2.readlines()

file1_lines.extend(file2_lines)
f1_f2_diff = list(set(file1_lines))
```